# Cookies not working on HTTPS pages on my site (C#)

Tags: ssl, cookies, https

I have alerts on my site (for a client) that are only displayed the first time a user visits the site each day, so the first page they load, the cookie is generated, and on all subsequent pages, so long as the cookie exists (and the date on the cookie matches the current date), the alerts will not be shows.

Some of the pages on the site use https, such as the donation page. On these pages, the alerts always show up. I assume this is because the cookie is being blocked. How do I get around this? This is the code I use for my cookies:

```
var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CHKD-Alert"];

// if cookie does not exist, create cookie
if (cookie == null)
{
    HttpCookie alertCookie = new HttpCookie("CHKD-Alert");
    alertCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d);
    alertCookie["dateSet"] = DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(alertCookie);
    AlertStyle = "display: block;";
}
else
{
    var dateSet = cookie["dateSet"];
    // if alert has already been shown
    if (cookie["dateSet"] != null && cookie["dateSet"] == DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString())
    {
        AlertStyle = "display: none;";
    }
    else
    {
        AlertStyle = "display: block;";
        Response.Cookies["CHKD-Alert"]["dateSet"] = DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString();
    }
}

ux_alerts.DataSource = alerts;
ux_alerts.DataBind();
```

EDIT: I added a second cookie for the HTTPS pages:

```
            var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CHKD-Alert"];
            var secureCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CHKD-Alert-Secure"];

            // if cookie does not exist, create cookie
            if (cookie == null)
            {
                HttpCookie alertCookie = new HttpCookie("CHKD-Alert");
                alertCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d);
                alertCookie["dateSet"] = DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(alertCookie);
                AlertStyle = "display: block;";
            }
            if (secureCookie == null)
            {
                HttpCookie alertCookieSecure = new HttpCookie("CHKD-Alert-Secure");
                alertCookieSecure.Secure = true;
                alertCookieSecure.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d);
                alertCookieSecure["dateSet"] = DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(alertCookieSecure);
                AlertStyle = "display: block;";
            }
            if (cookie != null || secureCookie != null)
            {
                var dateSet = cookie["dateSet"];
                // if alert has already been shown
                if ((cookie != null && cookie["dateSet"] != null && cookie["dateSet"] == DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString()) ||
                    (secureCookie != null && cookie["dateSet"] != null && secureCookie["dateSet"] == DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString()))
                {
                    AlertStyle = "display: none;";
                }
                else
                {
                    AlertStyle = "display: block;";
                    Response.Cookies["CHKD-Alert"]["dateSet"] = DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString();
                    Response.Cookies["CHKD-Alert-Secure"]["dateSet"] = DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString();
                }
            }
```

But the alerts still show up the first time the HTTPS page loads. They don't show after that, which is an improvement, but I don't want them to show the first time, if another page on the site has already been visited. As long as the HTTP cookie exists, the HTTPS cookie should exist

Comment: and this is what... javascript?

Answer (score 1):

In C# in the HttpCookie class there is a [Secure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.secure(v=vs.110).aspx) property that allows you to get and set cookies over HTTPS/SSL. I believe you'll need to set up conditions to set and get cookies over those HTTPS pages as well as the HTTP ones.

Cookies set over HTTPS should just work over HTTP so maybe just create a cookie using Secure. Sounds like since this is not set, the cookie is only being set on HTTP pages by default.

Comment: I added in a second HTTPS cookie, and the alerts are no longer showing up every time I view an HTTPS page, but they still show up on the first load, as if the HTTPS cookies isn't being written until the first time I visit the HTTPS page. I'll update my code above

Comment: You seem to still be writing both cookies if they don't exist. You need to actually check what protocol the page is using and dynamically set the right cookie.

I also assume you are receiving the "http content loaded over https" alert, perhaps just write secure cookie at all times as it will work over HTTPS and HTTP whereas the insecure cookie will not load over HTTP.

Comment: Oh, so the Secure cookie will work on the http pages?

Comment: Actually, I did some more research and while this applies to other areas like images and referrers, it is slightly different for cookies. I recommend reading this article, should help you in your endeavors: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-create-totally-secure-cookies